# An example for a planar graph with different embeddings with different degree sequences of the faces?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Let $G$ be a planar graph with a planar embedding with $f$ faces. The degree of a face $f_i$
is
the number $a_i$ of edges that are incident to $f_i$ (counting bridges twice). Assume that the
faces $f_1$, . . . , $f_f$ are ordered such that their degrees are non descending. Consider the degreesequence
($a_1$, . . . , $a_f$ ) of the faces.

Comment: Where is your question...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw a convex hexagon $ABCDEF$ and two diagonals $AC$ and $DF$. Then you have degreesequence $(3,3,4,6)$. If you draw $AC$ as an arc outside of the heaxagon, you have $(3,3,5,5)$.

Comment: Hello @HagenvonEitzen!!! Do you maybe know what cooperating topological sortings are?

Comment: @evinda Whatever I can imagine they are, I certainly cannot relate that subject to this graph.theoretic question